# postgres insert on conflict error - there is no unique or exclusion constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-update

I have two tables in postgres `daily_report` and `summary_songs`.

Sql file for creating the tables is here: https://nofile.io/f/Ef94rMFRh6C/file.sql

I want to update the `summary_songs` at the end of each day with below conditions:

- If the `userid` already does not exist, then record from `daily_report` need to be inserted into `summary_songs`
- If the `userid` exists, then `summary_songs.countid = summary_songs.countid+ daily_report.countid`.

I used below query to update `summary_songs`:

```
insert into summary_songs 
(select * from daily_report as B)
on conflict (userid, songd) 
do update set countid = countid+excluded.countid ;
```

I get below error:

> ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Answer (score 10):

To use `on conflict` you need to enforce a `unique(userid, songd)` on your `summary_songs` table:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2760e/3)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE summary_songs (
    date_time date  NOT NULL,
    userid integer NOT NULL,
    songd integer NOT NULL,
    countid integer NOT NULL,
    unique(userid, songd) 
);


CREATE TABLE daily_report(
    date_time date NOT NULL,
    userid integer NOT NULL,
    songd integer NOT NULL,
    countid integer NOT NULL
);


insert into daily_report (date_time, userid, songd, countid) values
(to_date('2017-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD'),  1 ,     1 ,       5),
(to_date('2017-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD'),  2 ,     1 ,      10),
(to_date('2017-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD'),  4 ,     1 ,       7);


insert into summary_songs (date_time, userid, songd, countid) values
(to_date('2017-12-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),1, 1,  80),
(to_date('2017-12-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),2, 1,  51),
(to_date('2017-12-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),3, 1,  66);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from daily_report
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2760e/3/0)**:

```
|  date_time | userid | songd | countid |
|------------|--------|-------|---------|
| 2017-12-31 |      1 |     1 |       5 |
| 2017-12-31 |      2 |     1 |      10 |
| 2017-12-31 |      4 |     1 |       7 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from summary_songs
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2760e/3/1)**:

```
|  date_time | userid | songd | countid |
|------------|--------|-------|---------|
| 2017-12-30 |      1 |     1 |      80 |
| 2017-12-30 |      2 |     1 |      51 |
| 2017-12-30 |      3 |     1 |      66 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
insert into summary_songs (date_time, userid, songd, countid)
select date_time, userid, songd, countid from daily_report
on conflict (userid, songd) 
do update set 
  countid = summary_songs.countid + excluded.countid ,
  date_time = excluded.date_time
```

**Query 4**:

```
select * from summary_songs
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2760e/3/3)**:

```
|  date_time | userid | songd | countid |
|------------|--------|-------|---------|
| 2017-12-30 |      3 |     1 |      66 |
| 2017-12-31 |      1 |     1 |      85 |
| 2017-12-31 |      2 |     1 |      61 |
| 2017-12-31 |      4 |     1 |       7 |
```